# spring thymeleaf - delete object from html table and pass id to controller

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I pass a list with objects from my controller to my html and thymeleaf creates a  for every object in the list.

I want to delete an entry via a button and pass the object id to my controller in order to delete it from the database.

However when I handle the post request in my controller the id attribute is emtpy.

HTML with Thymeleaf:

```
<tbody>
     <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
       <td th:text="${user.personId}"></td>
       <td th:text="${user.firstName}"></td>
       <td th:text="${user.lastName}"></td>
       <td>
           <form th:action="@{delete_user}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
              <input type="hidden" th:field="${user.personId}"/>
              <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
           </form>
       </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleDeleteUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    System.out.println(user.getPersonId());
    System.out.println("test");
    return "redirect:/external";
}
```

How can I make this work?
Or is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you may try changing the `th:action="@{delete_user}"` to `th:action="@{/delete_user}"`.
or you can use path variable/ query string and pass the id using get method.
e.g.
html:

```
<a th:href="|@{/delete_user/${user.personId}}|" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete_user/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleDeleteUser(@PathVariable String personId) {
    System.out.println(personId);
    System.out.println("test");
    return "redirect:/external";
}
```

or

html:

```
<a th:href="@{/delete_user(personId=${user.personId})}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete_user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String handleDeleteUser(@RequestParam(name="personId")String personId) {
    System.out.println(personId);
    System.out.println("test");
    return "redirect:/external";
}
```

Comment: deleting a user with the method=GET, is that a good practice ?

Comment: @user641887 Actually, you are not deleting the user by GET method here, you are just passing an id using GET method, the delete operation may be performed using some POST method web service.

Comment: I was able to get the Delete work using - RequestParam annotation. Delete does not work with @PathVariable. Trying to understand how they both are different.

Comment: Actually, I got it working both ways. Ignore my above comment. What's a better way to implement Delete in Spring - RequestParam or using PathVariable

Answer (score 3):

HTML with Thymeleaf :

```
  <table class="table table-responsive">

        <th >
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </th>

        <tr th:each="student : ${students}">
            <td th:text="${student.id}"/>
            <td th:text="${student.name}"/>
            <td th:text="${student.address}"/>
            <td >
              <form th:action="@{delete}" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="id" th:value="${student.id}" />
                  <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" />
              </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
private String deleteStudent(@RequestParam String id){
    System.out.println("Student_Id : "+id);
    return "redirect:/display";
}
```

OR

HTML with Thymeleaf :

```
  <table class="table table-responsive">

        <th >
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </th>

        <tr th:each="student : ${students}">
            <td th:text="${student.id}"/>
            <td th:text="${student.name}"/>
            <td th:text="${student.address}"/>
            <td >
                <a th:href="@{delete/__${student.id}__}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}")
private String deleteStudent(@PathVariable(name = "id") String id){
    System.out.println("Student_Id : "+id);
    return "redirect:/display";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is the view section.

```
<tbody>
<tr th:each="income : ${incomes}">
<td th:text="${income.createDate}"></td>
<td th:text="${income.name}"></td>
<td th:text="${income.description}"></td>
<td th:text="${income.amount}"></td>
<td><a th:href="@{/income/edit/{id}(id=${income.id})}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-user-edit ml-2"></i></a></td>
<td><a th:href="@{/income/delete/{id}(id=${income.id})}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-user-times ml-2"></i></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Below is the controller

```
@GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
public String deleteIncome(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id,Model model) {
    Income note = incomeRepo.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Income", "id", id));
    incomeRepo.delete(note);
    model.addAttribute("incomes",incomeRepo.findAll());
    return "viewIncome";
}
```

In the above code from the view section i'm passing the id to the controller. Then in the controller by finding the id, the relevant record is deleted.